# sandbox test and no receive any notification

Tags: asp-classic, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to install PayPal on an old classic asp website, but I have problem testing with the sandbox.

I can make payments which are accepted, but I see nothing on my notify.asp which is supposed to tell me if selling is ok or not. I wonder if I use the good address for testing on this page my code to know what is the answer status of PayPal is:

' PayPal verification

```
set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")

if err.number <> 0 then set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

str = Request.Form & "&cmd=_notify-validate"

objHttp.open "POST", "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", false

objHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

objHttp.Send str

if objHttp.status <> 200 then
    set objHttp = nothing
    Response.Redirect "error.asp"
end if

ret = objHttp.responseText
set objHttp = nothing

' Check notification validation
if (ret = "VERIFIED") then
     'payment is ok I write my database to confirm and send a email telling ok
     else
     'payment not ok I send a mail telling not ok
     end if
```

Where is my error, because I don't receive any mail?

Answer (score 1):

you will have enable Instant Payment Notification

By two method

1)in Merchant a/c >Profile > My selling tools > Instant Payment Notification.

2)You can also set the IPN URL on a per-transaction basis, in which case you don't need to set it up in your profile, by setting

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://yoursitename/notify.asp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built a CMS that has hooks to PayPal. If you think you might find clues by going through my code, here is a link to those asp files zipped up:
http://www.oceanmedia.net/files/PayPal.zip